# Add active class to child element

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am beginner with Vue.js (and bootstrap-vue) and I want to create tabs (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/u8Ld9bLw/1/))

```
<b-nav class="nav-tabs">
    <b-nav-item v-bind:active=true v-bind:class="{ active : tab === 1 }" v-on:click="tab = 1">Link 1</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item v-bind:class="{ active : tab === 2}" v-on:click="tab = 2">Link 2</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item v-bind:class="{ active : tab === 3}" v-on:click="tab = 3">Link 3</b-nav-item>
</b-nav>
```

But when I click on second link it doesn't change active=true (and active=false on first button). I tried

```
v-on:click:active=true
```

but it doesn't work. It works fine with tabs, but not with navs (e.g. https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/docs/components/tabs). Any idea?

Added:

Vue code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tab: 1
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you show your Vue JS code? Need to know how you're defining the component templates, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not familiar with bootstrap-vue, but I just did a bit of toying in their [playground](https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/play), and what you need to bind is the `active` property, bootstrap takes cares of the styles from that.

In other words, this seems to work:

```
<b-nav class="nav-tabs">
  <b-nav-item :active="tab === 1" @click="tab = 1">Link 1</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item :active="tab === 2" @click="tab = 2">Link 2</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item :active="tab === 3" @click="tab = 3">Link 3</b-nav-item>
</b-nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might need to add quotation marks in `v-bind:active="true"`but here is the general [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sdyntqz/). I am not using bootstrap-vue component, but it shouldn't be that difficult

Answer (score 0):

you can proceed like this

```html
<b-nav class="nav-tabs">
    <b-nav-item exact-active-class="active" to="/link-1">Link 1</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item exact-active-class="active" to="/link-2">Link 2</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item exact-active-class="active" to="/link-3">Link 3</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
```

property `exact-active-class`: `<router-link>` prop: Configure the active CSS class applied when the link is active with exact match. Typically you will want to set this to class name 'active'